# can't open Realm using mongodb sync

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I can't open a Realm. There is something wrong with my set up. This is the code in the app:

```
var configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "user=\(user.id)")
configuration.objectTypes = [User.self]
Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { [weak self](userRealm, error) in
                self!.setLoading(false);
                guard error == nil else {
                    fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)").   ///// here was my error before the edit (I changed the Permission Settings in Sync)
                }
```

Error code: "Fatal error: Failed to open realm: Error Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=89 "Operation canceled" UserInfo={Category=realm.basic_system, NSLocalizedDescription=Operation canceled, Error Code=89"

Screenshot of Mongodb Sync configuration

[image: Screenshot of Mongodb Sync configuration]

EDIT:
Replaced the Permission settings in Sync with the ones mentioned in the Task Tracker app and that got it connected:

[image]

EDIT: the configuration settings were changed to the below as per the suggestions from Jay.

```
var configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "\(currentUser.id!)")
```

Here is my Scheme definition for the User Collection:

```
{
"properties": {
"_id": {
  "bsonType": "string"
},
"_partition": {
  "bsonType": "string"
},
"name": {
  "bsonType": "string"
}
},
"required": [
   "_id",
   "_partition",
   "name"
],
"title": "User"
}
```

This is my User class in Xcode:

```
class User: Object {
@objc dynamic var _id: String = ""
@objc dynamic var _partition: String = ""
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "_id"
}
}
```

EDIT: I got this going to establish a connection by updating the Sync Permissions, so the app does not crash any more. However, now I am getting this message:

````
Connection to daemon was invalidated
Signup successful!
Log in as user: y
Login succeeded!
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = false, async open = false, client reset = falseSync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: client_reset_config = false, Realm exists = false, async open = false, client reset = false
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint '13.54.209.90:443' (from '.....:52139')
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Reading failed: End of input
2020-10-25...Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error```
````

I don't understand that the error "("Failed to open realm: (error!)")" in my above code is not triggered, but then in the log it says that the realm does not exist! So, what's going on here?

EDIT : this is the user table in mongodb, so I created some Users successfully.

[image]

EDIT : This is the log from mongodb

[image]

As we can see the User Id and the Request ID are not the same! I guess that the two IDs should be the same string in order to be authenticated, right??

I am following the Task Tracker app tutorial from the mongodb webpage for Swift to add the user login to my app. What am I missing here?

Comment: Realm asyncopen is obviously not working, but why?

Comment: I added an answer but I think you're dealing with two issues 1) connecting to Realm and then 2) Using custom configuration data from your User object. Also, you appear to be using a prior version of Realm so you should do a `pod update` noting that all the Realm function closure parameters change from `xxxx, error`, to a Result object so be prepared to update your code.

Comment: I added the updated log from mongodb and it shows that the User Id and the Request ID are not the same! I guess that the two IDs should be the same string in order to be authenticated, right??

Comment: can you explain what it means in the error log above "Sync: Connection[1]: Reading failed: End of input". Reading failed because of what?

Comment: Error:could not evaluate sync permissions with error: cannot compare to undefined (ProtocolErrorCode=206). Why does it say "compare to undefined"? I have the two user id strings in the log !!

Comment: also, it puzzles me that the error is in "permission" - do I have to set permissions somewhere??

Comment: by the way, I did the pod update as suggested above - just to confirm this

Comment: The issue at this point is you have too many variables and it's not clear what you're attempting to do. Are you attempting to use custom user data? If not then the User object has no bearing on the issues in question (it's not configured correctly for that anyway). If so, there are a lot of other components to make that work. I would suggest for the moment ditching your current Sync (Terminate sync) and use Development mode. Get your app connected and working and then worry about custom user info and permissions.

Comment: Oh - the userId in the screen shot of the authentication area and the partition key have no direct relationship. The bottom line is that whichever user it is, if they want to read data in a particular partition, that has to be specified in the `config` `let config = thisUser?.configuration(partitionValue: whichPartition)` - now `whichPartition` *could* be the users uid or it could be the string "banana" or "pfffft" or "yeeehaaaw" as long as it matches the partitionKey in the database, that data can be read.

Comment: I took your advise to ditch the current Sync and use Developer mode. There were too many things going on. I also started a new project from scratch. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complete guess, your config string is not correct

```
var configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "user=\(user.id)")
```

As that the partition value resolves to

```
partitionValue: user=Optional("5f1b586f757611faec257d88")
```

Try this

```
guard let user = your_app.currentUser() else {
    print("no user")
    return
}

guard let userId = user.id else {
    print("no user")
    return
}

var configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "user=\(userId)")
```

More to the point though, the partition value you're attempting to use is this string

```
user=5f1b586f757611faec257d88
```

and I think what you really want is use the user id

```
5f1b586f757611faec257d88
```

That's where I would start. If you're trying to leverage Realm rules, then something like `_partitionKey: "team_id=1234"` would work but that goes beyond the scope of the original question (and adds another layer of complexity - get it working first, then explore the rules).

Comment: added this to the code and configuration seems to be fine

Comment: @kangarooChris I think the issue is the same - you're telling realm the partition value is this `user= 5f1b586f757611faec257d88` and I am pretty sure you want a partition value of this `5f1b586f757611faec257d88` (not including the string `user=`)